# Could not load file or assembly 'Dapper, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I am unable to solve this problem, *"System.Exception : Could not load file or assembly 'Dapper, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."*

I have check the references in all of the projects in my solution, checked the nuget packages, checked the project file and cant find any reference to Dapper Version 1.8.0.0.

When I try and run tests it fails and I can't move my ASP.NET MVC application forward.

Any thoughts on what else to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to diagnose the DllNotFoundException is to enable fusion log viewer.
Here is what you need to do:
Open the Visual Studio Developer command prompt as an Administrator -> type in fuslogvw ->
-> Click settings -> select Log bind failure to disk (You can set a custom path for the log files). Run your application and start reading the logs (The log title will most likely contain your DLL name).
Don't forget to disable logging after you are done or your hard drive will be filled in no time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was that the Dapper.Rainbow 0.1.2 nuget package is dependent on Dapper 1.8 or greater and I had upgraded to Dapper 1.22. I ended up rolling back to Dapper 1.8 to get everything to work. So I will have to user Dapper 1.8 until the Dapper.Rainbow nuget package is updated.

Comment: @user865660, you are most welcome and thank you for sharing your findings with the community.

Comment: @user a "binding redirect" in web.config should fix that